# How can I get unique data without sql query

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm updating brand details in DB. But I'm getting multiple entries of the same name.
When running the following line:

```
$brand = $brands->brand;
```

The result of this `$brand` is

> puma,nike,puma,nike,puma,nike

I only want unique brand names, how can I do that?

Comment: Are you saving multiple entries "puma,nike,puma,nike,puma,nike" in brand field in table?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not super familiair with Laravel but the general idea is:

Create an `array`. For every name you get, check if it's already in the array, if not, add it to the array and process it. If it is already in the array, skip it.

**PHP example, not sure for Laravel**

```
$all_brands = array();
// Check if the brand is not already in the array
if(!in_array($brand, $all_brands)) {
    $all_brands[] = $brand;
    // Process the brand
} else {
    // Ignore entry
}
```

[PHP manual: in_array function](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

Answer (score 0):

you receive this number of brands because when you extract the brand from dataBase you extract every brand for every product. Try to extract just once.

Answer (score 0):

Try, if

```
$brands = ["puma","nike","puma","nike","puma","nike"];
```

then

```
$uniqueBrands = array_unique($brands);
```